# Sails.js - Using satellizer's interceptor with io.socket requests for adding an authorization header

Tags: angularjs, sockets, header, sails.js, satellizer

So I am learning right now the [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) framework and more specifically it's socket functionalities. For my frontend which is separated from the sails backend (API), I use AngularJS with [sails.io.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js) and for user authentication I am using [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer). So satellizer gives me already a nice ready functionally that I don't have to write. Like it's interceptor which adds an authorization header to each request to the API.

The problem is - when I use `io.socket` request like:

```
// Won't send authorization header to the backend
io.socket.post(url, params, function(data, res) {
    // handle response
});
```

The authorization header is not set by the interceptor. I have to do that manually with `io.socket.request` like that:

```
// Sends authorization header to the backend
io.socket.post({
    url: someUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        authorization: 'Bearer ' + $auth.getToken()
    },
    params: {
        // someParams
    }
}, function(data, res) {
    // handle response
});
```